# I need Dynamic query in BigQuery to find on which Date the Day Saturday has occurred in First week of Year 2021

Tags: sql, plsql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I need Dynamic query in BigQuery to find Date of Day Saturday has occurred in First week of Year 2021.

Consider the Day on date of 2022-01-01 is Saturday.
Therefore, I want to extract the date of last Year first week on which the Saturday was occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
with sample_dates as (
    select date
    from unnest(generate_date_array('2022-01-01','2022-12-31')) as date
)
select 
    date
    ,(select last_year_date
      from unnest(generate_date_array(date_sub(date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), date-1)) as last_year_date
      where extract(week from date) = extract(week from last_year_date)
      and extract(dayofweek from date) = extract(dayofweek from last_year_date)  
    ) as last_year_date
from sample_dates 
;
```

Given all of 2022 dates, this provides the same day of week for the same week in the previous year.

For example `2022-01-01` results in `2022-01-02` which is the first Saturday of the first week of last year.

If you're only looking for a single date the main portion would be the generating the appropriate date range with the `generate_date_array` function and then filtering based on the same week number and dayofweek value.

Answer (score 0):

Use below - should work for any year - just replace `2021` with whatever year you need

```
select date(2021, 1, 8 - extract(dayofweek from date(2021, 1, 1)))
```

Comment: Could anyone Please explain what is done here.

Comment: does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can help you!
You can find the first Saturday with a weekly cycle

```
declare
  i     number := 0;
  date1 date := date '2022-01-01';
  d     varchar2(20);
begin
  while i < 7 loop
    SELECT case
             when TO_CHAR(date1 + i, 'fmDay') = 'Saturday' then
              date1 + i
           end "Day"
      into d
      FROM DUAL;
    i := i + 1;
    dbms_output.put_line(d);
  end loop;
end;
```